# JSON Schema validation - both values should not be false at same time

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am using json schema validations for my project but stuck in this validation.
I have 2 values,
**boolean value1, boolean value2**
both values should not be false at same time.
either value1 or value2 should be true
Please help

Comment: doesn't seem like a schema validation to me. Rather one of the content

Answer (score 2):

The best option would be to take advantage of the `anyOf` keyword, which requires that at least one of the subschemas pass.

I expect your model looks something like

```json
{
  "value1": true,
  "value2": false,
  ...
}
```

To validate this, we need two schemas: one to validate `value1` is `true` and `value2` is `true`.  Then we put both of these schemas inside an `anyOf`.

Each of the property schemas looks like this:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "value1": { "const": true }
  }
}
```

This requires that `value1` is `true`.  Repeat for `value2` and put them in an `anyOf`.

```json
{
  "anyOf": [
    { "properties": { "value1": { "const": true } } },
    { "properties": { "value2": { "const": true } } }
  ]
}
```

Now you just add other validation like `type`, `required`, other properties, etc.